# Acessar aplicação JAVA web de outras máquinas

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly

Estou usando JAVA,JPA, com Wildfly,e primefaces.Tenho o link da minha aplicação http://localhost:8080/sicoob/faces/cadastroEstoque.xhtml
gostaria que outras máquinas acessassem esta aplicação, já modifiquei o localhost pelo IP da minha maquina mas não funcionou, existe algo específico a se fazer?

Answer (score 1):

O correto é configurar uma nova interface chamada any para qualquer endereço, ex:

```
<interface name="any">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```

e especificar ela como default no socket biding group, ex:

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: Alterando o socket e a interface funcionou corretamente,obrigado Heber e Dilnei.

Answer (score 0):

No wildfly, vá até o standalone.xml (ou domain.xml, depende de qual script você usa pra subir o servidor), e altera a linha abaixo:

De:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
```

Para:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração ,troquei "http://localhost:8080/sicoob/faces/cadastroEstoque.xhtml" por "10.54.31.85:8080/sicoob/faces/cadastroEstoque.xhtml" e não funcionou.

Comment: restartou o servidor? esse ip 10.54.31.85 é o seu mesmo?